# C++ How can i build byte arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, byte, winsock2

I am currently learning c ++ and i a beginner. Since not too strict to me: D

I programmed a winsocket udp client in c ++. This is now send bytes array (like `54-53-33-49-4E-49-54-31-00-65-00-00-88-06-3B-EC-E9-00-5A-6D-F3-12-C9-B6-6E-82-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00`) to a remote udp server. And this is my problem. I build the array in C # like that

```
byte[] sendData= new byte[versionLen + initTypeLen + 4 + 4 + 8];
byte[] Initversion = { 0x06, 0x3b, 0xec, 0xe9 };
Array.Copy(Initversion, 0, sendData, 0, versionLen);
[...]
```

Now in C ++ I have very strong problems. First I understood correctly that I have to build this in chars []?

My try:

```
char init1[/*VersionLength + InitPackLength + TimestampLength + 4 + 8*/ 9];
char Initversion[] = { 0x06, 0x3b, 0xec, 0xe9 };
char StepNumber[] = { 0x00 };

init1[0] = 0x06;
init1[1] = 0x3b;
init1[2] = 0xec;
init1[3] = 0xe9;
init1[4] = 0x00;
init1[5] = 0x06;
init1[6] = 0x06;
init1[7] = 0x06;
init1[8] = 0x06;
```

But the result: `06-3B-EC-E9` C++ remove all bytes after the `0x00`. How can i fix that? What is the right solution?

Thank you.

EDIT: Thats my code: https://paste.ee/p/vfYf4

Comment: Use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of a `char[]` array. To add values use the `push_back()` function.

Comment: What code is actually copying data into `init1`?

Comment: `But the result: 06-3B-EC-E9` that is because the next byte is `0x00` and if you print it out as a string it is interpreted as the string terminator. Do not print it out as a string.

Comment: @TheDude now i change the type to std::vector<uint8_t>. But the problem isn't fixed.

Comment: @KillzoneKid that is not right, the result string is from the remote udp server. And the client in c++ send only 4 bytes.

Comment: @VerHext You need to show more code including how you copy and send it

Comment: @KillzoneKid thats my code: https://paste.ee/p/vfYf4

Comment: @VerHext `strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buff.data()))` is your problem, I bet it returns 4, because as I mentioned before, it counts `0x00` as string terminator. Pass the actual length of the packet in bytes there.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thank you :D.  That was my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C and C++, regular character strings are terminated by a `'\0'` character. So it appears you are using a string function to copy the data. That is, it stops copying once it hits the `'\0'` value.

Interestingly, you left the part that copies the data (and maybe just the part the displays the data) out of your question. So we can't tell you which function that is. But we can see that's what's happening.